# React Native Post Request for a transactional Insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, react-native

Good day, please I created a page for payment  when the payment is successful, all the Items the user purchased, which are the items in the cartItems should be sent to mySql data base. I am using PHP as my server.

The problem I encountered is that the I get try post the cartItems is said to be undefined and the when I echoed out cartItems I got null

Errors:

```
Array ( )
Warning: Undefined array key "cartItems" in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\insertOrders.php on line 14

Warning: Undefined variable $_cartItems in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\insertOrders.php on line 16
NULL
Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\insertOrders.php on line 23
Cart items inserted successfully!
```

so the items where not inserted

This is the Php code:

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

// Prepare the SQL statement for inserting into orderProducts table
$insertOrderProductsStmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (userId, bookId, name, quantity, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?)");

// $jsonPayload = file_get_contents('php://input');
// $data = json_decode($jsonPayload, true);

// Get the cart items from the request
print_r($_POST);
// if(isset($_POST['cartItems'])){

    $cartItems = $_POST['cartItems'];
   echo $cartItems;
  var_dump($_cartItems);
  
  // Start the transaction
  $mysqli->begin_transaction();
  
  try {
      // Iterate over each cart item and execute the insert statement
      foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem) {
          $userId = $cartItem['userId'];
          $bookId = $cartItem['bookId'];
          $name = $cartItem['name'];
          $quantity = $cartItem['quantity'];
          $price = $cartItem['quantity'] * $cartItem['price'];
  
          // Bind the parameters and execute the statement
          $insertOrderProductsStmt->bind_param("iisii", $userId, $bookId, $name, $quantity, $price);
          $insertOrderProductsStmt->execute();
      }
  
      // Commit the transaction
      $mysqli->commit();
  
      // Close the prepared statement
      $insertOrderProductsStmt->close();
  
      // Send a success response
      echo "Cart items inserted successfully!";
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      // Rollback the transaction if an error occurred
      $mysqli->rollback();
  
      // Close the prepared statement
      $insertOrderProductsStmt->close();
  
      // Send an error response
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
  
  // Close the database mysqliection
  $mysqli->close();
// }
// else{
//     echo "an error occured";
// }

?>
```

This is my react native page :
the insertOrders is responsible for that and I called it in the onSuccess props of the Paystack component

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { cartTotalPriceSelector } from "../redux/selectors";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { color } from "react-native-reanimated";
import colors from "../config/colors";

import { clear } from "../redux/features/cart/cartSlice";

import { Paystack, paystackProps } from "react-native-paystack-webview";

const PaymentScreen = () => {
  // const isValidEmail = (email) => {
  //   const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
  //   return emailRegex.test(email);
  // };
  const paystackWebViewRef = useRef(paystackProps.PayStackRef);
  const totalPrice = useSelector(cartTotalPriceSelector);
  const userId = useSelector((state) => state.user.userId);
  const email = useSelector((state) => state.email.email);
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const cartItems = cart.map((cartItem) => {
    return {
      userId: userId,
      bookId: cartItem.bookId,
      name: cartItem.name,
      quantity: cartItem.quantity,
      price: cartItem.price,
    };
  });

  console.log("myItem",{ cartItems });

  const insertOrders = () => {
    const url = "http://192.168.11.102:80/api/insertOrders.php"; // Replace with the actual URL of your PHP page
  
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ cartItems }),
    };
  
    console.log("Before fetch request"); // Debugging statement
  
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Response received"); // Debugging statement
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("Result:", result); // Debugging statement
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  };

  

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Paystack
        paystackKey="*****************************************"
        billingEmail={email}
        amount={totalPrice}
        onCancel={(e) => {
          // handle response here
        }}
        onSuccess={(res) => {
          // handle response here
          Alert.alert("Payment successful");
          console.log("myItem",{ cartItems });
          insertOrders();
        }}
        ref={paystackWebViewRef}
      />
      <Image style={styles.image} source={require("../assets/payment.jpg")} />

      <View style={styles.totalContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.totalText}>₦{totalPrice}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.checkoutButton}
          onPress={() => paystackWebViewRef.current.startTransaction()}>
          <Text style={styles.checkoutButtonText}>Pay Now</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default PaymentScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  checkoutButton: {
    backgroundColor: colors.orange,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    borderRadius: 20,
    elevation: 3,
  },
  checkoutButtonText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#FFFFFF",
  },
  image: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    resizeMode: "cover",
    marginRight: 10,
    borderRadius: 11,
  },
  totalContainer: {
    margin: 10,
    borderColor: colors.lightOrange,
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 20,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  totalText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  emailInput: {
    height: 40,
    width: "100%",
    borderColor: colors.lightOrange,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 5,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  errorText: {
    color: "red",
    marginTop: 5,
  },
});
```

when I `console.log("myItems", {cartItems})` I got these response

```
myItem {"cartItems": [{"bookId": 18, "name": "The diary of a nigerian christian girl", "price": "2000.00", "quantity": 5, "userId": 31}, {"bookId": 21, "name": "A Time to Love", "price": "1500.00", "quantity": 3, "userId": 31}]}
```